# Adding modifier for mappings

Tags: contract-design, mapping, modifiers

can I add a modifier (for ex: onlyOwner) to a mapping? only I must see the value of mapping's key by myself(onlyowner).

For example:
`mapping (address => bool) onlyOwner getAddress;`

Thank you.

Comment: No, you cant. Everybody can (and should be able to) see the data on the blockchain, that's actually part of the whole idea (would you ever sign a contract without seeing the details?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually part of a broader concern.

You can put access control on a read-only function, but an adversary will:

1. Have all of your code
2. Have all of the data

Therefore, an adversary will get around any notion of confidentiality you construct. `private` doesn't change that. The most you can do is inconvenience a determined adversary.

Since it is transparent in any case, I generally advise against any restrictions on read-only functions and, in fact, incline to completely discoverable states.

Confidential information just won't exist in a contract state because it shouldn't be there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you Rob, I see. you're right :)